# Using jQuery to store client side Cookies for input fields, checkboxes, etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am not hoping for a full source code, but i will be grateful if someone shed some light on this.

Basically the situation is:

1. The user visits the web page, where he can filter the content based on the values of some selectboxes and checkboxes, etc.) I've done that part already to update the content dynamically based on the returned value or ID/name of field.
2. Now if the user Refresh the page, the filters will be lost. I refer to filters here, the checkboxes he checked, unchecked etc. No he will redo it again and thats not practical.
3. I wish to know if there is an easy way to save what the user checks as filters in cookies or something so that the form remains the same from his last visit. But I want to accomplish this without any server side work.

Can anyone shed some light or show me some steps or plugins that can allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use plain JavaScript, or use a [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie).

The plugin makes it a little friendlier to set them. In JavaScript, you do...

```
document.cookie = 'key=value; expires=Mon, 29 Nov 2010 23:40:00 UTC; path=/'
```

... to set them.

Comment: Oh nice! does this cookie plugin support input fields, checkboxes,etc.. thanks for your 2nd help for me today :)

Comment: @Ahmad Fouad Well you need to get the values first to store them. Serialise your form ( [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) ) and then store it in a cookie.

Comment: Do I have to serialize? I mean, I can't just set cookie names and values from the field name/value. Because I do not have a submit button on the form. it's just a form that updates content when any field is changed, without any buttons. just checkboxes, and some select boxes

Comment: @Ahmad Fouad No, you don't have to. But it will be more complicated, and clutter the cookies with a bunch of related key and value pairs.